# Anaconda Navigator fails to launch after successfully installed

Tags: anaconda

I have successfully installed the latest version of Anaconda Navigator in my local computer to get access to Jupyter notebook for a data science project, but when I try to launch it, it just flashes a black screen (console) and then disappeared. So how to fix this problem?
I need help please

However, I have uninstalled and reinstalled the application yet I cannot fix the problem, again when I try to update anaconda through the command prompt I got this message.

C:\Users\Momodu Sesay>conda update anaconda
'conda' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

So I am expecting to get solution(s) on how to fix this problem.